# How do I open .pls files?

Tags: internet-radio, shoutcast, winamp

I downloaded a `.pls` file for an online radio, but I can't open it. Winamp, VLC player all fail when opening, and [A Online Radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leadapps.android.radio) which according to the description can open this type doesn't show up in the "open with this" list.

What are my options?

Comment: Seems you have to wait a bit. Checking the description of [AStream Media Streamer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.customprogrammingsolutions.MediaStreamer), it says it will soon implement support for *pls (playlist files) which no app in the market currently can handle*. I searched, and in fact could not find any such app. Not sure if copy-pasting the URL(s) included with the `.pls` file would be any help...

Comment: I pasted the url from the file into the app but it didn't work either. I'll wait for the update, thanks.

Comment: Was worth a try. Crossing fingers they really make this update. Often enough something was to come "real soon now" (and never appeared at all)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested and [ServeStream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.servestream&hl=en) can open .pls files to play online radio (looks like [DeadBeeF Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.deadbeef.android&feature) and [Stream Furious](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.streamfurious.android.free) can as well.. When you click on the .pls link it should be an option to open with after it is installed.

Opening a web-linked .pls:

[image][image]

Then ServeStream opens the .pls file:

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Since `.pls` is just a playlist file with the location to the real audio files you could try to convert it to other playlist files and see if you can open them. Examples are `.asx` and `.m3u`.

If you open the `.pls` file with a text editor, you should be able to see the location to the sound url(s). If it is a single url, you could try to copy/paste that one into a streaming client.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to search for the streaming url and open it directly with this app: [radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uvencer.france_internationalradios).
After that you can add the link to favorites so that you'll not have to type it every time

Answer (score 0):

Try open it with [RadioNerd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.battlestr1k3.radionerd), it is quite easy to use and battery-saving :)